# VBA Macro: Designating Sheets() with vlaues in a worksheet

Tags: vba, excel, loops, dynamic-programming

I am trying to do the following:

There is a group of files of the same layout, and I would like to extract a specific page of each file and compile them together in one file.

I have manually created the compilation workbook, with each sheet named after the corresponding data source workbook.

I have created a loop that opens all the files and copy the specific sheet ("Target sheet"), but I am not sure how to paste them correctly.

Here is what I have so far:

```
Dim rw As Integer, prop As String
rw = 5
Do While rw < 44

prop = wb1.Sheets("summary sheet").Cells(rw, 3).Value

Workbooks.Open Filename:= "(file address)", UpdateLinks:=False

Set wb2 = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws1 = wb2.Sheets("Target sheet")
ws1.Range("A1").Copy Range("BA150")
wb1.Sheets(prop).Cells(1, 1).Paste
wb2.Close SaveChanges:=False
rw = rw + 1
Loop
```

Note: the file address contains some sensitive info so I did not post it here, but it is coded as such that it can be looped.

Since the sheet names can be found in a certain location in the summary sheet in the compilation file, I tried to code the "Sheets()" with dynamic reference to that list, but I am getting error messages "Run-time error '438' Object doesn't support this property or method", with the wb1.Sheets(prop).Cells(1,1).Paste being highlighted as the faulty line. Can someone suggest a solution to this? Thank you very much in advance!

======EDIT======

I found a solution thanks to the two comments - for future reference:

```
ws1.Cells.Copy Destination:=wb1.Sheets(wsn).Range("A1")
```

I used numerical sheet reference instead. Probably needed to amend the original code to: (not tested)

```
ws1.Cells.Copy Destination:=wb1.Sheets(""" & prop & """).Range("A1")
```

To make it work.

Comment: `ws1.Range("A1").Copy Range("BA150")`  This line effectively copies and pastes.  When you call `.Paste` on the next line, there's nothing copied I believe.  For a quick test, try changing the `.Paste` line to: `ws1.Range("A1").Copy wb1.Sheets(prop).Cells(1, 1)`

Comment: Great comment! Helped me find a workaround (with help of 3-14159265358979323846264). Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are copying the entire sheet, then you can use

```
wb2.Sheets("Target Sheet").Copy After:=wb2
```

Rather than copy/paste.

It basically copies the entire sheet to the other workbook.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - it helped me find a workaround.